# Additional params in URL for Django DetailView

Tags: django, django-generic-views

In Django's documentation for [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), it shows URLs like:

- `url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleDetailView.as_view(),
  name='article-detail'),`
- `url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),`

That is, it only allows for either the keywords `slug` or `pk`.
Is it possible to have an additional keywords in the URLs in addition to `slug` or `pk`, like:

`url(r'^(?P<author_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),`

Note the additional argument `author_slug` in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can access the additional kwargs via the `kwargs` dict in your view (assuming CBV).

For example, in a class-based view, you could `self.kwargs['memes']`

Note that this won't automatically say...do the object lookup for you (if you're writing a Detail View). You'd have to override `get_object()` for that.

Comment: There is no `request.kwargs`, only `self.kwargs`. Additionally, the kwargs are passed as keyword arguments to `dispatch()` and `get()`/`post()`.

Comment: @knbk Ah sorry. Guess I had some wires crossed. I'll amend my answer.